# Are unnecessary/unused templates instantiated?

Tags: c++, performance, templates, template-specialization

I have a function `void f<int N>()`.  `f` is only called with template parameters 1 and 2, e.g. `f<1>()` and `f<2>()` and I have efficiently specialized `f` for those two parameters.  `f` will never be called with any other parameter, but I have defined `f` with general `N` anyway, just for "clarity".  Question: **Will the compiler still instantiate this unused definition of `f<N>()`?**  If so, I feel like this will create code bloat, as I have dozens of functions of this sort located in very performance-critical areas of the program.

(Instead, I'm considering commenting the `f<N>()` definition and replacing it with an empty definition, i.e. `void f<N>(){}`.)

Comment: No, compiler will instantiate just for used function. **No code bloat for unused functions.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template is not instantiated unless it is used.

From Standards :

**§ 14.7.1/10**

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function
>   template, a member template, a non-virtual member function, a member
>   class, or a static data member of a class template that does not
>   require instantiation. It is unspecified whether or not an
>   implementation implicitly instantiates a virtual member function of a
>   class template if the virtual member function would not otherwise be
>   instantiated. The use of a template specialization in a default
>   argument shall not cause the template to be implicitly instantiated
>   except that a class template may be instantiated where its complete
>   type is needed to determine the correctness of the default argument.
>   The use of a default argument in a function call causes
>   specializations in the default argument to be implicitly instantiated.